# how do I make a stock fluctuation function in R?

Tags: r

I have a stock data named '**mytable**'

I want to create dataframe named 'diff_Close5'

I want to put data into diff_Close5. IF Stock Fluctuation rate reached +5% in last 5 days once(ex 20170704~20170710), 1 else 0

How do I make a code?

**  I can't speak English well. Sorry.   **

```
library(stocks)
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)
library(rpart)
filename = "C:/Users/Kun/Documents/Dashin/test.db" # db connect
sqlite.driver = dbDriver("SQLite")
db = dbConnect(sqlite.driver,dbname = filename)
database = dbListTables(db)
str(database)
database
mytable = dbReadTable(db,'A005930') #stock table

> head(mytable,10)
   Date Volume    Open    High     Low   Close diff_Close5
1  20170710 211888 2425000 2445000 2416000 2433000
2  20170707 162638 2387000 2406000 2381000 2393000
3  20170706 218461 2400000 2405000 2386000 2403000
4  20170705 212805 2341000 2384000 2339000 2379000
5  20170704 159220 2358000 2370000 2345000 2350000
6  20170703 136111 2375000 2389000 2356000 2361000
7  20170630 237551 2375000 2381000 2355000 2377000
8  20170629 166131 2402000 2416000 2397000 2397000
9  20170628 191450 2380000 2400000 2378000 2385000
10 20170627 192335 2411000 2420000 2395000 2415000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mytable$diff_Close5<- tail(mytable$Close, -1) - head(mytable$Close, -1)
```

Comment: Sincerely,Thank you for your support. But that code call a error. and I don't understand How that code calculate 5% rate.     mytable$diff_Close5<- tail(mytable$Close, -1) - head(mytable$Close, -1)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, diff_Close5, value = c(-40000, 10000,  : 
  replacement has 99 rows, data has 100